# Using Git/Hg repository as template project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, mercurial, tortoisehg

Is there a way to achieve something similar to what this guy does with SVN?
[How to use a subversion repository as a template for new projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682761/how-to-use-a-subversion-repository-as-a-template-for-new-projects)

I have a basic ASP.NET MVC project, which is essentially a simple CMS site, which I base new sites upon.

I do not like the idea of having to clone the repository into a new site every time because that creates multiple copies of the same repository in different locations, which doesn't seem clean enough to me.

Are branches the solution to my issue? Should I just create a new branch for a new site? That way I could be able to bring changes in both ways, which is a flexibility I'd very much like, support multiple project but still keep everything under one repo.

(sometimes a bug might be found in the new site where it would be fixed and we would want to bring the fix back into the source site and vice versa)

Please base you answer on both Git/Hg, I use both and also I believe they are similar enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that branches is not the thing which could help you. From the very basic times branching are used to work on the same project but in difference modes (maintenance, next version, new features adding and stuff like that) and creating new branch per new project is something which wrong from the conceptual point of view.

If you using git why not to create template project, save it to github and each time when you starting new project just to fork it on your machine, then creating new repository and pushing your new site to it. Think is a standard approach.

And if you want to create something advanced for that purpose - I advice you to create windows installer, which will install all stuff you need each time when you will starting new project.

Comment: I guess forking it is then. If someone else answers with a better advice, I might reconsider.

Comment: Isn't forking a repository on Github basically just creating a clone anyway? But with some added "githubbiness" (pull-requests, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

As @hyde says, cloning is kind of how a DVCS works, so you shouldn't really have a problem with that.

If however you are more interested in, for example, not being able to push back a sites changes to the template accidentally, then you could initialise a new repository, and before doing anything else `pull` from the template (I'm thinking in terms of Mercurial here, I would guess something similar is possible in Git):

```
$ hg init new_project
$ cd new_project
$ hg pull -u ../template
$ hg push
comparing with default-push
abort: repository default-push not found!
```

This sequence will create a new repository, updated with the latest template (including all changesets), but as it is not a direct clone, you will not be able to push changes accidentally back to the template.  However, as the initial changesets are the same, if you make a useful change to the template in your new project, you can still push it back by specifying the destination:

```
$ hg push ../template
pushing to ../template
searching for changes
no changes found
```

Creating your new repository from the template in this way also means that, while the repositories are not "linked" as such, it is simple to pull in recent template changes.

Comment: This is nice but isn't it essentially the same as forking? I decided to use the forking approach and it has served me well for the last couple of days (since asking this question). Then I simply request a pull. The only thing missing is that I don't know how to selectively accept a pull (there's 10 commits and I only want 2) or how to actually selectively put commits in the pull request itself.

Comment: It is basically the same idea as forking - it's simply how you could implement it locally without using something like github or bitbucket, which sometimes aren't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone the repository. If you want to avoid having multiple clones with different default branches, then do modifications to a site-specific branch, which will be the "default branch" for that site. You can then also trivially update the "template" code by pulling and merging.

If you want a clean start without (easy) option to apply changes from the template, then just get snapshot of the repository contents, and init a new repository from them.

---

> I do not like the idea of having to clone the repository into a new
>   site every time because that creates multiple copies of the same
>   repository in different locations, which doesn't seem clean enough to
>   me.

Well, that is what *distributed* version control systems do. Technically speaking, there is no central repository. "Central repository" simply means a particular clone, which everybody involved have more-or-less agreed to use for sharing their changes. Also it is entirely up to the DVCS users, what stuff they push to the central repository, and what they keep only in their clone(s).